# Creating a popup window for static websites when only html, css and jas can be used

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow, hugo, static-site

I am using Hugo static website generator and I was wondering for a static website that only has HTML, CSS, and javascript, how can I add a popup window to capture visitors email after a few seconds.

I have found [this article](https://www.classandobjects.com/tutorial/add_subscribe_button_on_static_site/), but I am not sure if it is a complete code and also instead of triggering at scroll down, I want a trigger after a few seconds.

Comment: This question is a little too broad. It would work the same way as you would if you had a static HTML, it has nothing to do with Hugo per se. You can setTimeout a function which will show a previously hidden overlay with your e-mail-form, and set a click-handler to the background and the x-button to hide it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Can you please point me to a resource/reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of setTimeout which after a certain time will prompt a box. After that you can do whatever you want with that email from the user.
You can call this method when the page loads or on click.

```
emailCapture = () => {
  setTimeout(()=>{
  const email = window.prompt("Please give us your email","example@mail.com");
}, 2000)
};
```

Here is an example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VyJQJQ

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I have it run without clicking anything? So when user is on my page it automatically popup?

Comment: window.onload = function() {
 emailCapture();
};